# RegEx Whitelist Problem

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I'm a little confused. I am running all my inputs through a basic sanitize function I write to only allow certain characters, but characters such as `[]` are still being allowed.

```
function sanitize($input) {
$pattern = "/[^a-zA-z0-9_-]/";
$filtered = preg_replace($pattern, "", $input);
return $filtered;}
```

Any idea why it's doing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo in your pattern string that's causing the problem

```
/[^a-zA-z0-9_-]
```

You want A-**Z** instead.

---

btw: you might be interested in the character class [[:alnum:]](http://docs.php.net/regexp.reference.character-classes) and/or the [PCRE_CASELESS modifier](http://docs.php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers)

Answer (score 4):

Adding to others answers.

`[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is same as `\w`, a word char.

So `[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]` can be written as `[^\w-]`

Answer (score 2):

You have to capitalize the second "z": "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/"

Answer (score 0):

Don't take for granted that `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is the same as `\w`, though. On http://se.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php it says that `\w` "may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place".